# XSLT: How to change attribute names as well?

Tags: xslt

This code is able to change elements to attribute key/value pairs. I want to change the attribute names in the same logic. How to do that?

Input:

```
<TESTSEQUENCE> 
  <TESTCASESTARTTIME>2014-05-02 16:02:38</TESTCASESTARTTIME> 
  <TESTCASENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15 </TESTCASENAME> 
  <SCRIPTFILENAME>/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl</SCRIPTFILENAME> 
  <TXTLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15/TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.txt</TXTLOGFILENAME> 
  <HTMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html</HTMLLOGFILENAME> 
  <XMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.xml</XMLLOGFILENAME>
  <STARTTIME>1399039358</STARTTIME> 
  <TOTALCMDS>27</TOTALCMDS>
  <NOTOKIDS>27</NOTOKIDS> 
  <NOTOKCMDS>{CETP ABORT}</NOTOKCMDS> 
  <FAILURESTRINGS>1=Failed,</FAILURESTRINGS> 
  <RESULT>ABORTED</RESULT> 
  <FINISHTIME>1399039672</FINISHTIME> 
</TESTSEQUENCE>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="TESTSEQUENCE">
    <testcase>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </testcase>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<testcase time="2014-05-02 16:02:38" name="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15 " scriptfilename="mct/tc/Traffic.tcl" txtlogfilename="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.txt" url="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html" xmllogfilename="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.xml" starttime="1399039358" target_connect="" totalcmds="27" notokids="27" notokcmds="{CETP ABORT}" failurestrings="1=Failed," status="ABORTED" finishtime="1399039672">
</testcase>
```

Comment: Please provide sample input data (XML), and an example for the desired output as well. Do you mean you want to change attributes to elements??

Comment: "*I want to change attribute name also in the same logic.*" Change it to what?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the attribute names to lower-case? Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: for example::   HTMLLOGFILENAME  to url    RESULT to status  like that

Comment: Your example does not explain the **logic** behind the change. Do you have a list that maps the original element names to the new attribute names? Also please answer the question regarding your version of XSLT.

Comment: TESTCASESTARTTIME to time         TESTCASENAME to name          HTMLLOGFILENAME to url           RESULT to status            I need these 4 attributes to be changed

Comment: I am new to XSLT so dont have much idea about it. I am using xslt 1.0

Comment: I have rolled back your question to the previous version, because that is the version that has been answered and your new question has practically nothing to do with the problem that was solved here. I suggest you mark this question as answered and post a new one with the new problem. Note that the XML you have posted, with multiple TESTSEQUENCE elements, is not valid XML: you must have a **single** root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TESTCASESTARTTIME to time TESTCASENAME to name HTMLLOGFILENAME to url
>   RESULT to status I need these 4 attributes to be changed

You need to exclude these 4 elements from the generic `xsl:for-each` applied to the other elements, and handle them explicitly:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="TESTSEQUENCE">
    <testcase>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[not (self::TESTCASESTARTTIME or self::TESTCASENAME or self::HTMLLOGFILENAME or self::RESULT)]">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:attribute name="time">
            <xsl:value-of select="TESTCASESTARTTIME"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="TESTCASENAME"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="url">
            <xsl:value-of select="HTMLLOGFILENAME"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="status">
            <xsl:value-of select="RESULT"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </testcase>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input of:

```
<TESTSEQUENCE> 
  <TESTCASESTARTTIME>2014-05-02 16:02:38</TESTCASESTARTTIME> 
  <TESTCASENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15</TESTCASENAME>   
  <SCRIPTFILENAME>/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl</SCRIPTFILENAME> 
  <TXTLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15/TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.txt</TXTLOGFILENAME> 
  <HTMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html</HTMLLOGFILENAME> 
  <XMLLOGFILENAME>TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.xml</XMLLOGFILENAME>
  <STARTTIME>1399039358</STARTTIME> 
  <TOTALCMDS>27</TOTALCMDS>
  <NOTOKIDS>27</NOTOKIDS> 
  <NOTOKCMDS>{CETP ABORT}</NOTOKCMDS> 
  <FAILURESTRINGS>1=Failed,</FAILURESTRINGS> 
  <RESULT>ABORTED</RESULT> 
  <FINISHTIME>1399039672</FINISHTIME> 
</TESTSEQUENCE>
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testcase SCRIPTFILENAME="/proj/cpptemp/dt/network_repo/398/int/IEXS_CRX901185_1/iov/cbm1-3_mct/tc/Traffic.tcl" TXTLOGFILENAME="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15/TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.txt" XMLLOGFILENAME="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.xml" STARTTIME="1399039358" TOTALCMDS="27" NOTOKIDS="27" NOTOKCMDS="{CETP ABORT}" FAILURESTRINGS="1=Failed," FINISHTIME="1399039672" time="2014-05-02 16:02:38" name="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15" url="TRAFFIC_MIXED_COLD_TP-A15.html" status="ABORTED"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.... it is working fine for me.     I have 1 more query.... I need to count results .... pass fail aborted...and then need to show as attributes for parent tag

Comment: @user3460401 I don't understand your question. There is only one result in your example XML.

Answer (score 1):

Please enhance your code:

```
<xsl:template match="TESTSEQUENCE">
    <testcase>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{concat('ABC-',name())}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </testcase>
  </xsl:template>
```

OR

```
<xsl:template match="TESTSEQUENCE">
    <testcase>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{if (name()) = 'TESTCASESTARTTIME' then 'TESTCASES' else ()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </testcase>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: As You can see , I have so many attributes here... I want different name for different attribute.... then need to use so may if else ??

Comment: Why do you want to make them attributes in the first place? They contain data, they are supposed to be elements. http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp. @NavinRawat: isn't `if...then...else` XPath 2.0? Most people use XSLT 1.0 processors, thus XPath 1.0.

Comment: Yes you are right that's why I put two different answer to indicate how user can get expected result.

Comment: It relates to XPath 2.0. You need to use XSLT 2.0 in this case. And if you are using same, please share your code with us.